# Remove Ubuntu and restore DOS, not Windows

Tags: uninstall

I would like to uninstall Ubuntu and bring my laptop back to DOS. I don’t have Windows on it. All the examples I have seen use Windows to uninstall. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a live Ubuntu disk/usb, you could

- "clear" the Ubuntu partitions. You would run `gparted`, choose your hard drive and format to "cleared" any partitions you want to effectively erase. I believe it is equivalent to running `wipefs` on the partition, though it does not really erase or overwrite the data.

  [Excerpt from man page]

  > wipefs - wipe a filesystem signature from a device
  >
  > DESCRIPTION
  >          wipefs can erase filesystem or raid signatures (magic strings) from the specified
  >          device to make the filesystem invisible for libblkid.  wipefs does not erase  the
  >          filesystem  itself nor any other data from the device.
- Or you could just create a new Partition Table (in GParted, under the Device menu), that would erase (hide) all the partitions on the drive.

Then you would need a DOS install disk to install just DOS, though I don't think they're easy to find, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) the final MS-DOS release was in 2000. All the DOS install disks I've seen have been actual floppy disks, not many laptops have a floppy disk drive. You might want to try a web search for "reinstall windows", I found this site that sounds promising http://www.windowsreinstall.com/

OR just installing Windows (or DOS) will often overwrite any Ubuntu stuff, Windows is traditionally excellent at ignoring anything on your hard drive and just installing itself over top (whether you want to erase the other things or not). So first I'd try not removing Ubuntu, and just install something else.

Answer (score 2):

Xen2050's answer pretty much sums it up. However there is another option:

- **Install FreeDOS**

[FreeDos](http://www.freedos.org/) is IMHO the best option you have today if you want "DOS". Unlike the microsoft counterpart, the guys of FreeDOS did continue the development. So you have a decent, up-to-date "DOS experience".

Installation instructions are [here (general overview)](http://freedos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Install) and [here (specific for VirtualBox but should apply to all PC's)](http://freedos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox).

Answer (score 0):

As **Ubuntu** has no license, there is no specific advantage in first removing it (before installing something else). Therefore, there is NOT even any formal definition what an 'uninstall' might do.

---

- Backup any data or settings you still need, on to external media.
- Choose what OS you want on your Laptop, and proceed with install.

Comment: "As Ubuntu has no license"...this is in so many ways wrong.

Comment: I meant commercial / paid license. *And you could perhaps explain your views, rather that state unsupported opinion.*

Comment: I understood your point, which is why I did not downvote. Αs for my point: the difference between a GPL license and no license or a public domain license and why it is important to not just ignore these differences would definitely cross the boundaries of what a comment is meant for...and I don't need to explain to a 10K rep user that what you wrote is factually wrong.